# Find lines in Visual Studio which are not comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to use Visual Studio "Find in Files" tool window to find ALL lines having a certain phrase in them but filter by NON-comment lines at the same time?

There must be a regular expression? Or a link to the regexp help?

Comment: You know, this is actually pretty useful

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro is it? In a good codebase I can't think of a really good reason for this. I'm sure there are edge cases though.

Comment: As a side note, if too many comments are getting in the way of the code then perhaps it's time to get rid of some of the comments.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Well, just remember that there's code you inherit.

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro that's the edge case.

Comment: @David Keep in mind there's code you inherit. Sure, by the time you had the time to get rid of useless comments, you surely don't need this anymore. But until then.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich In this specific case I need to get rid of all 'a is TypeB' expressions within a 200k lines project, because it makes problems on Xamarin... Sure, in a perfect world there would be no problems at all.

Comment: @user492238 interesting, have you tried contacting Xamarin?

Comment: not yet. The workaround would even improve the code base quality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select "Use Regular Expressions" in the "Find in Files" window and enter the following phrase in the search box:

```
^(?!(\s*/+)).*phrase
```

If you want the phrase to stay as a single word:

```
^(?!(\s*/+)).*\s+phrase\s+
```

Regarding the help: in regexp mode there is a small button next to the search box: [(a)+] 
It opens a short list with common regexp commands. At the end of that list there is a link to the msdn documentation.

Comment: Great. I was struggling with the negating '?!' syntax. As far as I remember it was '^' earlier?

Comment: Ah! Found it on the msdn side to mentioned. It was an 'old' syntax. You have the 'new' one. Obvious!

Comment: This wouldn't handle multiline comments.

Comment: You are right. I doubt it is possible to handle multiline comments reliably with regular expressions. The same issue as parsing XML with regexp.

Comment: It would be great if it were possible. Maybe we could exclude strings as well?