# regex where lines doesn't start with spaces and "//"

Tags: regex

I would like to perform a grep using a regex that will search for lines that contain the string "debug(" but do not start with zero to any number of spaces followed by "/" 2 or more times. I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789351/find-lines-in-visual-studio-which-are-not-comments), but the result was excluding some results like `/debug($file)`
I have tried multiple variations including:

- ^(?![/]{2}\s+)\s*.*debug(
- ^(?![/]{2,}).*debug(
- ^(?![/]{2,}\s?)\s*(?!//).*debug(
- ^(?![/]{2,}\s?)debug(

```
   //debug($user); should not match
        debug($file); SHOULD match
debug($file); SHOULD match
// debug($file); should not match
     // debug($file); should not match
```

I know i am close but can't quite get there
Thanks in advance

EDIT: @anubhava provided the correct regex `^(?!\s*//).*debug\(`

Comment: Try: `^(?!\s*//).*debug\(`

Comment: ````^(?!(\s*\/+)).*debug\(```` worked for me from the tagged duplicate post

Comment: `^(?!(\s*\/+))` is incorrect because it will fail the match for `/ debug($file);` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex:

```bash
^(?!\s*\/\/).*debug\(
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TQTJC5/1)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!\s*\/\/)`: [Negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to fail the match if we have 0 or more whitespaces followed by `//` at the start
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `debug\(`: Match `debug(`